# Localise settings section headline

Tags: plugins, options, localization

Assuming i've got a bunch of setting sections. I add these sections to my plugin page in the following way.

```
$sections = array('notifcations', 'updates');

foreach ($sections as $section)
{
    add_settings_section(
        $section .'_section',
        $section,
        array( $this, 'disable_callback_warnings' ),
        'sgnc'
    );
}
```

Everything works as expected but i wonder how to localise the section headline? As far as i know i can't pass any variables to the locale functions `_e()` and `__()`. So this won't work:

```
$sections = array('notifcations', 'updates');

foreach ($sections as $section)
{
    add_settings_section(
        $section .'_section',
        __($section),
        array( $this, 'disable_callback_warnings' ),
        'sgnc'
    );
}
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localize the headings in your initial array:

```
$sections = array(
    'notifcations' => __( 'Notifications', 'your_text_domain' ), 
    'updates' => __( 'Updates', 'your_text_domain' )
);

foreach ($sections as $section => $header )
{
    add_settings_section(
        $section .'_section',
        $header,
        array( $this, 'disable_callback_warnings' ),
        'sgnc'
    );
}
```